# How to free allocated memory to an array of pointers after assigning value?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

A simple beginner's dilemma so it should be quickly apparent.

I am trying to free allocated memory from a variable inside of the array of char pointers

This throws no error:

```
    array= malloc(1*sizeof(char *) + 1);
    array[0] = malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
    free(array[0]);
```

Yet if I add some value to it, I get an error:

```
    array= malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
    array[0] = malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
    array[0] = "a";
    free(array[0]);
```

(malloc: *** error for object 0x10......: pointer being freed was not allocated
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug)

How could this be explained and how to deal with this?

Comment: If you want to store `"a"` at `array[0]`, use [`strcpy`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/). Note, that's most likely supposed to be `array[0] = malloc(2*sizeof(char));` (not `size(char*)`). In general, the space you `malloc` should be `sizeof(`<one-level-up>`)` of the lvalue you're assigning to. Furthermore, `sizeof char` is always 1, so some SO users advocate omitting it entirely, in this case leaving you with `array[0] = malloc(2);`

Comment: That explains. My thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `array` is to be a list of pointers to *strings* (each of which will take data such as the 2-character, `"a"`), then there are a couple of errors in your approach.

First, the `array[0]` (and other elements) should be allocated as `sizeof(char) * 2` (not `sizeof(char*) * 2`) – that will give pointers to buffers that can each hold up to 2 characters (the `a` letter and the `nul`-terminator).

So:

```c
    array= malloc(2*sizeof(char *));    // An array of two char* pointers
    array[0] = malloc(2*sizeof(char));  // One pointer to a 2-character buffer
//...
```

Then, when you want to assign a given string to one of the elements, use the `strcpy` function, as shown below. What your `array[0] = "a";` line does is to *replace the address of the allocated buffer* with the *address of the string literal* – and, as you didn't allocate that, you can't free it (and you then can't even free your *actual* allocated buffer, as you've 'lost' its address).

```c
//...
    strcpy(array[0], "a"); // Copy the second argument's data to the first
    // ... later on ...
    free(array[0]);        // This will now (still) work, as you didn't change the address
    // ...
    free(array);           // And don't forget to free the array of pointers!
```

Note, also, that `sizeof(char)` is **defined** (by the C Standard) to be 1 byte, so you can omit that in the second line of the first snippet above (but you *need* it in the `sizeof(char*)` case – the size of a pointer will vary between platforms and compilers).

Answer (score 1):

@Adrian Mole is totally correct, and I just want to add a few comments about string literal.
String literal constants lie in the .rodata segment of the program, which is a pre-allocated, read-only segment occupying the program memory space. You cannot free or modify any value in this segment in any case, so

```
array[0] = "a";
array[0][0] = array[0][0] + 1;
```

will also cause an error.